# UK travel days with quarantine

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, nigerian-citizens, quarantine

Good day. Please I want to confirm if I want to visit the UK for 7 days then I need to quarantine for 10 days. On the application form, it asks for how many days do I intend to stay in the UK.
Should I mention 7 days or should I add the 10 days quarantine to the 7 days making it 17 days?

Comment: Do you intend to spend your entire visit in quarantine? If not, you should state the combined total.

Answer (score 4):

Even though you won’t enjoy much of anything during the quarantine period, you will be in the UK during that time, so you must include that in the duration of your stay (and account for the associated costs, as well as where exactly you will be staying during that time).

However, you probably need to have a very good reason to come to the UK in these circumstances. They probably won’t find it very reasonable for someone to spend 10 days in quarantine for 7 days of sightseeing for instance.

Comment: I want to spend 20 days, of 10 days will be for the quarantine and 10 days for sight seeing. How do I explain it on the application form.

Comment: I also want to confirm, the question says how much do u intend to spend on your trip. I wrote 1200 gdp and my husband wrote 1500 gdp. We are both traveling with my infant daughter and my uncle is accommodating us through out our 20 days stay in the uk. Air ticket will cost us about 620 gdp each. Hope the 1200 gdp and 1500 gdp we budgeted for the trip is acceptable.

Comment: @Luvlyspot Just state on the form that you intend to stay for 20 days. I think there's a section where you describe your itinerary or activities, you should specify the 10 days in quarantine there. I still think any ECO will be quite suspicious of a visa application at this time for this reason, so your application must be bulletproof. Remember you are not allowed to leave the place you have designated for quarantine (not even for a stroll or to go to the shop) and you can't have anyone coming to that place that doesn't live there. No family, no friends.

Comment: @Luvlyspot Also you need to be tested before travelling, as well as twice during the quarantine period (about £200 per person).

Comment: @Luvlyspot As for how much you're going to spend, that's probably a new question. Don't forget to factor in the costs of the tests.